# How to enable production mode for twilio whatsapp notification

Tags: notifications, twilio, whatsapp

How i can Enable production mode for twilio whatsapp notification.
I can't see any option in project setting for enable production mode.
I have done process for upgrade project.

Answer (score 2):

To use WhatsApp in production (outside the Sandbox), you will need to apply for enabling a Twilio number, the details of which can be found below.

[Getting Started with Twilio for WhatsApp (Beta)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007721954-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-for-WhatsApp-Beta-)

[Twilio API for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api)

Comment: @Alan I need to to send whatsapp message to US & UK. Do i need to purchase different from-numbers for each country.

Comment: You do not. You can us, a Twilio WhatsApp enabled US Number or UK number, to send 1-way or 2-way WhatsApp messages to all supported destinations.

Comment: my requirement is to sent whatsapp notification to different counties us, uk, uae, australia .. etc

Comment: so i can do that from a Twilio WhatsApp enabled US Number, right? @Alan

Thank for your help

Comment: Correct, you are not required to use International numbers to send internationally with WhatsApp.